# Flask sqlalchemy record all changes in the table is not working

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have written below given code... i want to record all changes(before commit + after commit) done in `User` table and store them as a JSON format in `User2` table. Storing them in JSON is working fine; 
but `flask-sqlalchemy`'s `before_models_committed` is not working. i thought i will record before change in `before_change` function and after change in `after_change` function;

i get `obj.as_dict()` in `after_commit` function but not in `before_commit`

 in docs https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-SQLAlchemy/signals.html they are saying that `before_models_committed` works exactly same as `models_committed`


 any better way to do this????
or how to solve below issue????

```
from sqlalchemy.types import TypeDecorator, VARCHAR
from sqlalchemy.ext.mutable import Mutable

import json
from bson import json_util

class JSONEncodedDict(TypeDecorator):
    impl = VARCHAR

    def process_bind_param(self, value, dialect):
        if value is not None:
            value = json.dumps(value, default=json_util.default)
        return value

    def process_result_value(self, value, dialect):
        if value is not None:
            value = json.loads(value, object_hook=json_util.object_hook)
        return value


class MutableDict(Mutable, dict):
    @classmethod
    def coerce(cls, key, value):
        if not isinstance(value, MutableDict):
            if isinstance(value, dict):
                return MutableDict(value)

            return Mutable.coerce(key, value)
        else:
            return value

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        dict.__setitem__(self, key, value)
        self.changed()

    def __delitem__(self, key):
        dict.__delitem__(self, key)
        self.changed()

JsonType = MutableDict.as_mutable(JSONEncodedDict)

from flask import Flask, request, Response, jsonify, g
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy, models_committed, connection_stack, before_models_committed
from flask_login import current_user
from datetime import datetime

from time import sleep
import csv, json

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///flask_test.sqlite'
# app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///:memory:'

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True)
    pub_date = db.Column(db.DateTime)

    def __init__(self, username, email):
        self.username = username
        self.email = email
        self.pub_date = datetime.utcnow()

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User %r>' % self.username

    def as_dict(self):
       return {c.name: getattr(self, c.name) for c in self.__table__.columns}

class User2(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(80))
    olddata = db.Column(JsonType)
    newdata = db.Column(JsonType)
    updatedtime = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    event = db.Column(db.String(30))

    def __init__(self, username, olddata, newdata, event):
        self.username = username
        self.olddata = olddata
        self.newdata = newdata
        self.event = event
        self.updatedtime = datetime.utcnow()

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User %r has commited some change>' % self.username

    def as_dict(self):
       return {c.name: getattr(self, c.name) for c in self.__table__.columns}

@app.route("/change")
def change_test():
    username, email = request.args.get("username"), request.args.get("email")
    admin1 = User.query.filter_by(username=username).first()
    if username and email:
        if admin1:
            admin1.email = email
            db.session.commit()
            return Response(json.dumps({"username": username,
                                        "email": email,
                                        "update": True}), mimetype='application/json')
        else:
            admin = User(username, email)
            db.session.add(admin)
            db.session.commit()
            return Response(json.dumps({"username": username,
                                        "email": email,
                                        "insert": True}), mimetype='application/json')
    else:
        return Response(json.dumps({"error": "please enter username and email"}), mimetype='application/json')

@before_models_committed.connect_via(app)
def before_change(sender, changes):
    print "Before Change:::"
    print "Sender", sender
    print "changes: "
    for obj, change in changes:
        print "\t", obj, change
        print "Details: "
        print "\t", obj.as_dict()

from sqlalchemy.orm.attributes import get_history

@models_committed.connect_via(app)
def after_change(sender, changes):
    print "After Change:::"
    print "Sender", sender
    print "changes: "
    # s2 = db.create_scoped_session({'scopefunc': connection_stack.__ident_func__})

    for obj, change in changes:
        # for x in obj.__table__.columns:
        #     history=get_history(changes, x)
        print "\t", obj, change
        print "Details: "
        print "\t", obj.as_dict()
        # admin1 = User.query.filter_by(username='admin').first()
        # print "Before change2::", admin1.as_dict()




db.create_all()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True, threaded=True)
```

and recording only "after_commit" changes; i wrote below code, but here i have to create another session; and here too; i am no where getting `before_commit` values!!!

```
@models_committed.connect_via(app)
def on_models_committed(sender, changes):
    s2 = db.create_scoped_session({'scopefunc': connection_stack.__ident_func__})
    for obj, change in changes:
        if change == "update" or change == "delete":
            curr_user = current_user
            if not curr_user:
                curr_user = "anonymous"

            user2 = User2(curr_user, obj.as_dict(), change)
            s2.add(user2)
            s2.commit()
    s2.close()
```

and terminal log is:

```
After Change:::
Sender <Flask 'app'>
changes: 
    <User u'testname'> insert
Details: 
    {'username': u'testname', 'pub_date': datetime.datetime(2014, 11, 13, 11, 24, 32, 592000), 'id': 2, 'email': u'testname@gmail.com'}
127.0.0.1 - - [13/Nov/2014 16:54:32] "GET /change?username=testname&email=testname@gmail.com HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

## Update 1:

Here is the more detailed terminal log

```
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/
 * Restarting with reloader
After Change:::
Sender <Flask 'app'>
changes: 
    <User u'testname'> insert
Details: 
    {'username': u'testname', 'pub_date': datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 9, 5, 8, 2, 433000), 'id': 1, 'email': u'testname1@gmail.com'}
127.0.0.1 - - [09/Jan/2015 10:38:02] "GET /change?username=testname&email=testname1@gmail.com HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [09/Jan/2015 10:38:02] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 -
After Change:::
Sender <Flask 'app'>
changes: 
    <User u'testname1'> insert
Details: 
    {'username': u'testname1', 'pub_date': datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 9, 5, 8, 19, 9000), 'id': 2, 'email': u'testname11@gmail.com'}
127.0.0.1 - - [09/Jan/2015 10:38:19] "GET /change?username=testname1&email=testname11@gmail.com HTTP/1.1" 200 -
After Change:::
Sender <Flask 'app'>
changes: 
    <User u'testname'> update
Details: 
    {'username': u'testname', 'pub_date': datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 9, 5, 8, 2, 433000), 'id': 1, 'email': u'testname2@gmail.com'}
127.0.0.1 - - [09/Jan/2015 10:38:31] "GET /change?username=testname&email=testname2@gmail.com HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

and output of `pip freeze` is as below:

```
alembic==0.6.7
backports.ssl-match-hostname==3.4.0.2
blinker==1.3
certifi==14.05.14
cffi==0.8.6
click==3.3
colorama==0.3.2
cryptography==0.6.1
decorator==3.4.0
diesel==3.0.5
dulwich==0.9.9
email==4.0.2
Flask==0.10.1
Flask-Bcrypt==0.6.0
Flask-Bootstrap==3.2.0.2
Flask-Bootstrap3==3.1.1.3
flask-cache==0.13
Flask-Login==0.2.11
Flask-Migrate==1.2.0
flask-mongoengine==0.7.1
Flask-Script==2.0.5
Flask-Session==0.1.1
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.0
Flask-SQLAlchemySession==0.0.1
Flask-Storage==0.1.0
Flask-Uploads==0.1.3
Flask-WTF==0.10.2
freeze==0.8.0
GitPython==0.1.7
greenlet==0.4.5
ipython==2.3.1
itsdangerous==0.24
jdcal==1.0
Jinja2==2.7.3
jsonpickle==0.8.0
Mako==1.0.0
MarkupSafe==0.23
matplotlib==1.4.2
mongoengine==0.8.7
mysql-connector-python==1.0.12
networkx==1.9.1
nltk==3.0.0
numpy==1.8.1
openpyxl==1.8.6
pbr==0.10.0
psutil==2.1.3
PuLP==1.5.6
py==1.4.25
pycosat==0.6.0
pycparser==2.10
pymongo==2.7.2
PyMySQL==0.6.2
pyOpenSSL==0.14
pyparsing==1.5.7
pyreadline==2.0
pysoundcard==0.5.0
pytest==2.6.3
python-dateutil==2.3
pytz==2014.10
pywin32==219
PyYAML==3.11
pyzmq==14.4.1
requests==2.4.3
schedule==0.3.1
scikit-learn==0.15.2
scipy==0.13.3
simplejson==3.6.5
six==1.8.0
SQLAlchemy==0.9.8
sqlalchemy-migrate==0.9.2
sqlparse==0.1.13
Tempita==0.5.2
tornado==4.0.2
trie==0.1.1
Twiggy==0.4.5
Twisted==14.0.2
uuid==1.30
validator==2.0.6
validator.py==1.2.0
validators==0.7
virtualenv==1.9.1
webapp2==2.5.2
Werkzeug==0.9.6
wheel==0.24.0
Whoosh==2.6.0
wrapt==1.9.0
WTForms==2.0.1
xlrd==0.9.3
xmldict==0.4.1
zope.interface==4.1.1
```

Comment: Please edit your answer with the output of ```pip freeze``` so we can see which versions of everything you're running.

Comment: @opyate: i have updated the post with output of `pip freeze` and also added more detailed terminal log of running app.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that those signals are not working at all at the moment due to a bug in Flask-SQLAlchemy. A [pull-request](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask-sqlalchemy/pull/256) with the fix is already merged and perhaps will be released in version 2.1 of Flask-SQLAlchemy.

Comment: @namit: I think you've misunderstood. This doesn't work because of a bug. There is no working example.